# Getting 'module' object has no attribute 'ExtractValuesToPoints_sa' error in ArcPy while extracting values to points?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I am using ArcGIS 10.

I am trying to extract values to point using ArcPY but getting error as

> Runtime error : 'module' object has
>   no attribute 'ExtractValuesToPoints_sa'

Below is what I am trying

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

shape="G:\\Input\\ShapeFiles\\SA_Fishnet_0025_Points.shp"
raster="G:\\Input\\RasterFiles\\SA_Zonal_0025d.tif"
output="G:\\Input\\RasterFiles\\SA_Zonal_0025d_Zonal_PYTHON.shp"

arcpy.ExtractValuesToPoints_sa(shape, raster, output,"NONE","VALUE_ONLY")
```

I can do it without using ArcPy, but here I am learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it..

Python snippet which I copied from results as

```
arcpy.ExtractValuesToPoints_sa(shape, raster, output,"NONE","VALUE_ONLY")
```

should be replaced by

```
ExtractValuesToPoints(shape, raster, output,"NONE","VALUE_ONLY")
```

Since, I have already imported `arcpy` and  `arcpy.sa` we need not to call it again in `arcpy.ExtractValuesToPoints_sa`.

I tried to explained it based on my understanding. As I posted this I thought I should answer it.